# Separate select label options and get values in input in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

How about, I have a `<select>` tag which is filled with the BD.
What I want to do is that when selecting the desired option, that the `<select>` values are assigned to different `<input>` tags.

Currently I select some of the options, I get the value and the text of the option. I want to have them as 2 different options.

In my example I have this `<select>`

```
<option value = "1"> Pizza1 Pizza2 </ option>
```

My question is how to separate the text of the option so that Pizza 1 is in one option and Pizza2 is in a different option.

So that something like this:
[image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#">

    <select name="choose_food" onchange="showValue(this.value); showValue2(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);">

      <option value="1">Pizza1 Pizza2</option>
      <option value="2">Hamburger1 Hamburger2</option>
      <option value="3">Bacon1 Bacon2</option>

    </select>

    <br/>

    <input type="text" name="food" id="food" value="" />

    <br/>

    <input type="text" name="food2" id="food2" value="" />

    </form

  </body>
  </html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var showValue = function(x){
    document.getElementById('food').value=x;
  }



  var showValue2 = function(x){
    document.getElementById('food2').value=x;
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. Are you asking how to create option values dynamically? Is this a PHP or JS question?

Answer (score 0):

Just put them in different option values as follows:

```
<option value="1">Pizza1</option>
<option value="2">Pizza2</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got what you mean. To make them different options, you just have to put them into different option tags, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="#">
    <select name="choose_food" onchange="showValue(this.value); showValue2(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);">

      <option value="1">Pizza1</option>
      <option value="2">Pizza2</option>
      <option value="3">Hamburger1 Hamburger2</option>
      <option value="4">Bacon1 Bacon2</option>

    </select>

    <br/>

    <input type="text" name="food" id="food" value="" />

    <br/>

    <input type="text" name="food2" id="food2" value="" />

    </form

  </body>
  </html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var showValue = function(x){
    document.getElementById('food').value=x;
  }



  var showValue2 = function(x){
    document.getElementById('food2').value=x;
  }
  </script>
```